# Find the lastest date in oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle, row-number, rownum

I have a big trouble with the query in the oracle database ver.10. What I want is to find the last date `dateofstat` 
I have try many solutions, but it works but it take too much time. 
- Using rownum
- Using row_number()
- Using rank()

There are my tries:
**1. rownum**

```
select dateofstat from (
select  stat.dateofstat from dhg.statistics stat
join (
  select distinct assetid from dhg.relatedasset
     where (`CONDITION1`)
  MINUS
  select distinct assetid from dhg.relatedasset
 where (`CONDITION2`)
) grs 
on stat.assetid = grs.assetid
order by stat.dateofstat desc
)where rownum = 1
```

Explain plan:
[image]

**row_number()**

```
select dateofstat from (
  select stat.dateofstat,
    row_number() over (order by stat.dateofstat desc) rnumber
  from dhg.statistics stat
  join (
    select distinct assetid from dhg.relatedasset
    where (`CONDITION1`)
    MINUS
    select distinct assetid from dhg.relatedasset
    where (`CONDITION2`)
  ) grs 
  on stat.assetid = grs.assetid
) where rnumber = 1
```

Explain plan:
[image]

**rank()**: This solution I did try but it gives repetitive rank number, because of it, I dont think that I should used this solution to find the top one.

I dont know what should I do now, really need help. For testing, I use sqlplus on emacs, without `rownum` I take less than 3 second to get the first rows of this query.

```
select  stat.dateofstat from dhg.statistics stat
join (
  select distinct assetid from dhg.relatedasset
     where (`CONDITION1`)
  MINUS
  select distinct assetid from dhg.relatedasset
 where (`CONDITION2`)
) grs 
on stat.assetid = grs.assetid
order by stat.dateofstat desc
```

I wonder that I could have any workaround solution by this tweak.

**UPDATE SOLUTION STATUS FROM @ANTON**

```
select  max(stat.dateofstat) from dhg.statistics stat
join (
 select distinct assetid from dhg.relatedasset
     where relatedasset.assetid in (191759.0, 3.0, 5.0, 98.0, 99.0)
   or relatedasset.linkid in (3232.0, 1049.0, 1057.0, 1067.0, 102.0, 1032.0, 104.0, 105.0, 1051.0)
 MINUS
 select distinct assetid from dhg.relatedasset
     where relatedasset.assetid in (192106.0, 1014.0, 10302.0)
   or relatedasset.linkid in (210.0, 737.0, 126.0, 1053.0, 1054.0, 119.0, 3133.0)
 ) grs 
 on stat.assetid = grs.assetid
```

I must say, I did work for once, very weird behavior. In the first executing I take only 3 seconds to execute, but in second time, I take much much more time (I did not count). Here are explain plan:

[image]

In addition, I also did try the second solution which use `exist` and `not exists`, however, it does not work well.

```
select  max(stat.dateofstat)
from dhg.statistics stat
where exists(select *
           from dhg.relatedasset rasset
           where stat.assetid = rasset.assetid
           and rasset.assetid in (191759.0, 3.0, 5.0, 98.0, 99.0)
           or rasset.linkid in (3232.0, 1049.0, 1057.0, 1067.0, 102.0, 1032.0, 104.0, 105.0, 1051.0)
            )
and not exists (select *
           from dhg.relatedasset rasset2
           where stat.assetid = rasset2.assetid
           and rasset2.assetid in (192106.0, 1014.0, 10302.0)
           or rasset2.linkid in (210.0, 737.0, 126.0, 1053.0, 1054.0, 119.0, 3133.0)
            )
```

This query, the plan give me a painful result. 
[image]

Comment: If you're really chasing down a performance problem, then it looks like you're going about it the wrong way, and haven't provided us with the most important part of your query: `condition1` and `condition2`.  That's what's causing the full table scans.  Have you checked that the columns used in those conditions are properly indexed?

Comment: I did provide condition1,2 in detail, please see

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to the various OR conditions (IN and OR) on `relatedasset` the DBMS decides to perform a full table scan. That seems reasonable. So what can we optimize? We can see to it that the full table scan is done just once. Query the table, group by `assetid` and check with HAVING if the first condition was true for any record and the second for none.

You can also use a parallel hint to make Oracle perform the full table scan in parallel if possible.

```
select  max(dateofstat)
from dhg.statistics
where assetid in
(
  select /*+ parallel(relatedasset,4) */ assetid
  from dhg.relatedasset 
  group by assetid
  having 
    max( case when assetid in (191759.0, 3.0, 5.0, 98.0, 99.0) 
                or linkid in (3232.0, 1049.0, 1057.0, 1067.0, 102.0, 1032.0, 104.0, 105.0, 1051.0) 
         then 1 else 0 end ) = 1
  and
    max( case when assetid in (192106.0, 1014.0, 10302.0)
                or linkid in (210.0, 737.0, 126.0, 1053.0, 1054.0, 119.0, 3133.0) 
         then 1 else 0 end ) = 0
);
```

Comment: I must say, your solution's crazy. It works like charm with less time. Now I have to analyze your solution, why do it work so fast. Thank you indeed

Comment: I have a question, the `in` clause can only handle 1000 elements, however, You use a subquery here, so does it cause trouble in long term. In fact, the subquery right after IN (subquery) return more than 6000 results

Comment: Yeah, the limit is just on literals. (And it's a limitation that I really hate. Everytime I have more than thousand literals, I must spilt them into separate IN clauses that I combine with OR or use a temporary table. Oracle could just as well allow for more than 1000 literals and do the same thing under cover.)

Answer (score 3):

Why so complex?
if you need just last date, you may use max() function:

```
select  max(stat.dateofstat)
from dhg.statistics stat
join (
  select distinct assetid from dhg.relatedasset
     where (`CONDITION1`)
  MINUS
  select distinct assetid from dhg.relatedasset
 where (`CONDITION2`)
) grs 
on stat.assetid = grs.assetid
```

If dhg.statistics table is not too big and you may presume that you need to probe just several records with highest dateofstat to find one that sutisfies your relatedasset requirements, then you may rewrite query like this:

```
select  max(stat.dateofstat)
from dhg.statistics stat
where exists(select *
               from dhg.relatedasset asset1
              where (`CONDITION1`)
                and stat.assetid = asset1.assetid)
 and not exists (select *
               from dhg.relatedasset asset2
              where (`CONDITION2`)
                and stat.assetid = asset2.assetid)
```

But if you need to do too much probes in relatedasset table to find statistics that you need, you may have worse performance.
**UPDATE TAKING INTO ACCOUNT NEW PLANS**
Sstan is right, as `statistics` table is big (71M), and minus result is small (5), you just need proper indexing of relatedasset table
I'd suggest index by `relatedasset.assetid` and by `(relatedasset.linkid,relatedasset.assetid)` to avoid table scan at all.
By the way, you missed brackets in second query 
(as `AND` has higher priority then `OR` so taking `CONDITION1` and `CONDITION2` in brackets is required to achive correct WHERE condition),
 so you get plan much worse than it could be. But anyway with such data distribution even correct version will perform slower then your varian with proper indexing.

Comment: I did try but it does not work well, I did post solution status in the question update. please take a look at this

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're just missing indexes. Make sure you have indexes on:

- `relatedasset.assetid`
- `relatedasset.linkid`

Once you do that, then all your attempted queries will perform much better.